# Partial View not printing values in mvc 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I'm using ajax call to execute partial view controller action to print max batch number. Everything executes, but the value doesn't print in partial view. On selected dropdown list I'm calling ajax method to execute. Below is my code that i'm using.

**Models.Batch.cs**

[Required]

```
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Batch Number")]
    public string BatchNumber { get; set; }
```

**BatchController.cs**

```
public PartialViewResult GetBatchNumber(string CourseID)
        {

            Context.Batches contBatch = new Context.Batches();
            Models.Batches b = new Models.Batches();
            b.BatchNumber = contBatch.GetallBatchList().ToList().Where(p => p.CourseId == CourseID).Select(p => p.BatchNumber).Max().FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            ViewBag.Message = b.BatchNumber;
            return PartialView(b);
        }
```

**CreateBatch.cshtml**

```
 <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseId, Model.Courses, new { id = "ddlCourse" })
            <div id="partialDiv">
                @{
                    Html.RenderPartial("GetBatchNumber", Model);
                }

            </div> 
            <script>
                $("#ddlCourse").on('change', function () {

                    var selValue = $('#ddlCourse').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '/Batch/GetBatchNumber?CourseId=' + selValue,
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: "",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#partialDiv").html(data);
                        },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert('oops something went wrong');
                }
                });
                });
            </script>


            </div>
```

**GetBatchNumber.cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Batches

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BatchNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BatchNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BatchNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `dataType: "json"` would be throwing an exception - your calling a method which returns html - change it to `dataType: 'html'` (or just delete it altogether)

Comment: It was just simple thing to notice. Thank you Sir :)

Comment: And suggest you use `url: '@Url.Action("GetBatchNumber", "Batch"),` and `data: { CourseId: selValue },`

Comment: And its a bit pointless using `LabelFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` in your partial since you do not have a form control for `BatchNumber` (your just generating text for it.

Comment: True! Thanks for the valuable suggestions also. I'll keep these in mind :)